# EF6 returns wrong data from database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and Entity Framework 6 in my ASP.NET project. To initialize the main menu, I'm fetching a view data to a List variable in the C# language :

```
using (var db = new DBEntities())
{
    ImageGroupList.AddRange(db.vw_image_groups.OrderBy(x => x.id)
                                              .ThenBy(x => x.abbreviation).ToList());
```

But the result is not the same as I see in SQL Server Management Studio.

Here is the SQL Server view query result in SSMS:

[image]

Also, I've printed the 'ImageGroupList' values by a loop :

```
foreach (var item in ImageGroupList)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.id + ", " + item.parent_id + ", " + item.abbreviation + ", " + item.text + ", " + item.member_count + ", " + item.type + ", " + item.order_index);
```

Here is the result :

[image]

As you compare both results, the data of abbreviation column in Entity Framework isn't the same as SQL Server view result!

I mixed up! Who knows what happened here?

Edited :
Mapping details
[image]

Comment: Likely nobody, since you do not show the code that might be causing the issue...

Comment: Show us the mapping. It seems like you may have wrong mapping for this column.

Comment: I uploaded the mapping screenshot!

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue, but it is important to remember that SSMS and the underlying .NET SQL provider can give different plans for the same query due to each using different SET options.
https://groupby.org/conference-session-abstracts/advanced-query-tuning-techniques-2/

Comment: Thanks, everyone. The problem solved by @marc_s's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a subtle problem with *views* when used from Entity Framework.

If you have a table, to use it with EF, you need to have a **primary key** to uniquely identify each row. Typically, that's a single column, e.g. an `ID` or something like that.

With a view, you don't have the concept of a "primary key" - the view just contains some columns from some tables.

So when EF maps a view, it cannot find a primary key - and therefore, it will use *all non-nullable columns* from the view as "substitute" primary key.

I don't know what these are in your case - you should be able to tell from the `.edmx` model.

When EF goes and reads the data, it will read the first line and create an object for that.

When EF reads the second line, it notices that the "primary key" (the collection of all non-nullable columns in your dataset) is the same as before - so it doesn't bother creating a new object with those values read, but the primary key is the same, it hence must be the same object as it has already read before, so it uses that object instead.

So the problem really is that you can't have explicit primary keys on a view.

Either you can tweak your EF model to make it clear to EF what is really the "primary key" (you need to make sure those columns are both **non-nullable**) - or you need to add something like a "artificial" primary key (using e.g. a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` construct) to your view.

By adding this `RowNum` column to your view, which just numbers the rows 1, 2, ...., n, you get a new, non-nullable column which EF will include into the "substitute PK" and since those numbers are sequential, no two rows will have the same "PK" values and therefore none will erroneously be replaced by something that's been read from the database already.

**Update:** @YounesJafari: your mapping **exactly** supports what I'm saying; your view's "primary key" is on (`id`, `parent_id`) - and in the case of the first two rows from your view, those are **identical** -- therefore, EF will take the first row (`id=0, parent_id=-1, abbreviation=en`) twice - it will consider the second row from the view (`id=0, parent_id=-1, abbreviation=fa`) to be **identical** to the first (because they have the **same values** for `id` and `parent_id`) .....

Comment: I uploaded the mapping screenshot! It seems PK and FK are exist.

Comment: Right... And your PK is only id+parent_id which have repeateded values in your view. You'll have to do as the answer says and make more columns part of the PK or create an artificial one

Comment: Thank you very much @marc_s. Yes! I changed 'EntityKey' of 'abbreviation' to 'True' and now Its ok.